# Power BI Pro limitations

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[From Power BI pricing page](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/#powerbi-comparison-table) I see that Power BI Pro allows only 8 refreshes per day and max 1 GB dataset.

Questions:

1. *8 refreshes per day: accross all datasets or per single dataset?*
2. *Is this a common practice how to deal with max dataset threshold?* Even Power BI Pemium limit of 10 GB looks not enough for me. I would like to build reports based on atomic fact tables, they could be 10+ GBs. Is MPP layer and DirectQuery the only option for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. The refresh limit of 8 is per dataset, not overall. This is usually enough in most scenarios
2. Even with Power BI premium you cannot exceed more than 10GB per dataset. You will be able to go a little over 10 GB once the data is uploaded, but the first upload has to be below 10 GB. That being said Power BI compresses the data a lot, so it's going to take a huge load of data for you to cross the limit. If you run into this issue, then the best solution would be to use a direct query. As mentioned above, I highly doubt you are going to exceed the 10 GB limit, you might want to import your data into Power BI desktop and then check the size before going for Direct query

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm I right that Power BI can import parquet data from ADLS? Than I think i won't benefit a lot from compression, since my parquet data are already compressed with snappy

Comment: Yes, you should be able to import the data and it looks like compression might not have a big effect, but I would still suggest you test the size of the data within Power BI..